# Unit Tests Not Appearing

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 on the Windows 8 Release Preview and I can't seem to get my unit tests to appear in the test explorer.

I have a class called TestApp.Entity, and TestApp.EntityTest...

Here is my code:

```
namespace TestApp.Entity.Test
{
    using System;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework;
    using TestApp.Domain;

    [TestClass]
    public class EntityTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public async void TestObject1Deserialize()
        {
            Uri agencyUri = new Uri("*removed*");
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(agencyUri);

            string responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            List<Agency> agencyList = Deserializers.AgencyDeserialize(responseBodyAsText);

            CollectionAssert.Contains(agencyList, new Agency() { Tag = "*removed*", Title = "*removed*", ShortTitle = "", RegionTitle = "*removed*" });
        }

    }
}
```

I assume that's all I needed to do, but they still don't appear in the test explorer. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Windows 8 RTM is out. And you need to make your unit tests `async Task` instead of `async void` for them to work correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary), "you need to make your unit tests `async Task` instead of `async void` for them to work correctly".

This fixed the problem and the tests appeared. It's odd that no errors appeared when I used void, but now I know. Thank you!

Comment: Not works in vs 2012, man...Neither with [Test] or [TestCase]. [TestMethod] wasn't there too...

Answer (score 2):

I have Visual Studio 2012 and i couldn't see the Tests in Test Explorer,

So I installed the following: [NUnit Test Adapter](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d)

That fixed the issue for me !

Answer (score 1):

Do a rebuild all on the application, including any projects that contain test classes and test methods. They should appear in [Test Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx) soon after.

Comment: Yea, the problem was that they weren't showing up after the rebuild. I had to change the async void to async task to fix the issue.

Comment: This fixed it for me, too.  That is not very intuitive to fix that.  Why would MS make the test async void?  Is that to allow/assume other testing frameworks like NUnit?  Even if it does, that still doesn't make much sense to me.